# postgresql: check if there is any rows at all before using limit 1

Tags: postgresql

I have a huge table of data. I am looking for something which may or may not exist yet

So when i do

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE col='test'
```

I get

```
No rows found.

Total runtime: 70.147 ms

SQL executed.
```

Where as when I try

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE col='test'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I see it hangs may be because the table is too big

How can i avoid this situation

Comment: Is `col` unique? What about `id`? What indices do you have defined on that table? Please also add the query plans for the two queries.

Comment: `col` is not unique. it can have repetivite texts. Indices are defined on `col`

Comment: I am looking for something like `IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM tablename WHERE col='test') THEN SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE col='test' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; END IF;`

Comment: No, you're looking for an index covering both `col` and `id`.

Comment: thanks this worked, When i added the index with `col` and `id`, its now very fast